# Having trouble displaying saved criteria using NSRuleEditor

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsruleeditor

I setup a `NSRuleEditor` for user to edit rules to filter an array, I have no trouble for user to edit rules, but I couldn't find a way to display the rules that I saved for user, does anyone have any ideas?

I have rules prepared for each row and returned from the delegate methods, when the user clicked the "+" button, the new rule appeared as I expected

```
#pragma mark - NSRuleEditorDelegate

- (NSInteger)ruleEditor:(NSRuleEditor *)editor numberOfChildrenForCriterion:(nullable id)criterion withRowType:(NSRuleEditorRowType)rowType {
    RuleCriterion *ruleCriterion = criterion;

    if (rowType == NSRuleEditorRowTypeCompound) {
        if (ruleCriterion == nil) {
            return self.compoundCriteria.count;
        } else {
            return ruleCriterion.numberOfChildren;
        }
    } else {
        if (ruleCriterion == nil) {
            return self.simpleCriteria.count;
        } else {
            return ruleCriterion.numberOfChildren;
        }
    }
}

- (id)ruleEditor:(NSRuleEditor *)editor child:(NSInteger)index forCriterion:(nullable id)criterion withRowType:(NSRuleEditorRowType)rowType {
    RuleCriterion *ruleCriterion = criterion;

    if (rowType == NSRuleEditorRowTypeCompound && ruleCriterion == nil) {
        return self.compoundCriteria[index];
    } else if (rowType == NSRuleEditorRowTypeSimple && ruleCriterion == nil) {
        return self.simpleCriteria[index];
    } else {
        return [ruleCriterion childAtIndex:index];
    }
}

- (id)ruleEditor:(NSRuleEditor *)editor displayValueForCriterion:(id)criterion inRow:(NSInteger)row {
    RuleCriterion *ruleCriterion = criterion;

    return ruleCriterion.displayValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a row with

```
- (void)insertRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex withType:(NSRuleEditorRowType)rowType asSubrowOfRow:(NSInteger)parentRow animate:(BOOL)shouldAnimate;
```

Set the criteria and display values of the row with

```
- (void)setCriteria:(NSArray *)criteria andDisplayValues:(NSArray *)values forRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex;
```